# Getting all values comma separated as last option in ng-repeat

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a select in which I am using `ng-repeat` to generate options. I am trying to have a last option as `All` which should have comma separated values of all the options

```
<select ng-model="facilityIdForEquipment" ng-change="loadFacilityEquipments()" >
      <option value="" selected>(Please select)</option>
      <option ng-repeat="facility in Facilities" value="{{facility.value}}">{{facility.text}}</option>
      <option value="">All Facilities</option>
</select>
```

I want to have comma separate values of all the options values in my `All Facilities` options. Something like this

```
<option value="1809,856,3214">All Facilities</option>
```

I can modify the object while loading these values from js but is there any way I can do this on markup using angular?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to return csv.

```
<option value="{{ getValues(Facilities)}}">All Facilities</option>
```

method

```
$scope.getValues(facilities){
    return facilities.map(function(f){
        return f.value;
    }).join(',');
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this way it can be achieved but I am searching if there is any way that is not dependent to controller method but can be achieved directly from the markup. Ofcourse only if the way exists!